# Why does Solr numFound count differ from facet_counts

Tags: solr, lucene, faceted-search

I want a count of how many Solr hits there are for the string "lincoln". I ask Solr in this way:

```
?wt=json&rows=0&q=lincoln
```

Solr responds with JSON that includes a count:

```
"response":{
  "numFound":24552
  "start":0
  "maxScore":956939.2,
  "docs":[]
}
```

So far, so good. Now I want to know how many hits there are for **two** strings, "lincoln" and "douglas".

I could make two queries. This approach will become cumbersome with larger numbers of strings, however, so I'd like to combine the queries. I believe combining them is possible with faceting:

```
?wt=json&rows=0&q=*:*&facet=true&facet.query=lincoln&facet.query=douglas
```

Solr responds with something that surprises me:

```
"response":{
  "numFound":7992943,
  "start":0,
  "maxScore":1.5185139,
  "docs":[]
},
"facet_counts":{
  "facet_queries":{
    "lincoln":5958,
    "douglas":1998
  }
}
```

The surprise is that the "lincoln" count is 5958 when my previous query lead me to expect 24552. The count for "douglas" is similarly low.

How does counting with `q=lincoln` differ from counting with `facet.query=lincoln`

Comment: Attach `debug=all` to your query - since you're using the default parameters for the query parser, they might be searching through different fields. Try being explicit (i.e. `field:lincoln`) in both cases.

Comment: Interesting. Output from `debug=all` is quite long. What am I looking for in particular?

Comment: It'll tell you exactly how your query is being parsed and what parameters are active for your query - that should be able to tell you something about exactly why these queries differ. You can attach the parsed query and the request information to your question.